# Changing CRS from Geographic to Projected on vector layer

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3

I am trying to run a Iso-Area as Interpolation (from Point) calculation using QNEAT3 in QGIS 3.8.2.

To do so, I need to change the CRS from Geographic to Projected. I did that to my raster layer, but when I try to do the same to any of my vector layers, they just disappear.

I am trying to change it from EPSG:4326 - WGS 84, to EPSG:25832 - ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N.

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @WojtekAntoni! How did you change the CRS of your raster and vector layers?

Comment: thanks! right click on the layer in the toolbar -> set CRS -> set layer CRS. Then I searched for the one I needed and double clicked on that.

Comment: For any kind of analysis, make sure to ***reproject*** it which saves the spatial data in the new CRS. For vectors, you can use the `Reproject layer` tool; for rasters, you can use the `Warp (reproject)` tool. Both of these are available from the Processing Toolbox.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Most welcome, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 3):

For any kind of analysis, make sure to reproject it which saves the spatial data in the new CRS. For vectors, you can use the Reproject layer tool; for rasters, you can use the Warp (reproject) tool. Both of these are available from the Processing Toolbox. – Joseph